# Python factorial by recursion

Tags: python, recursion

When calculating factorial by recursion, why does this code work:

```
def factorial(x):

    if x == 1:

        return x

    return factorial(x - 1) * x
```

But this doesn't:

```
def factorial(x):

    if x == 1:

        return x

    return factorial(x) * (x - 1)
```

Both seem very similar to me, can someone explain and go through stack trace, help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean in this instance?

Comment: Because the second form calls `factorial()` with the *exact same value for `x` each time*. You created an endless loop. `factorial(5)` is not the same as `factorial(5) * 4`, that's just endlessly replacing the `factorial()` call with itself.

Answer (score 4):

Well, when we define the factorial we said that `n! = n*(n-1)!`, on your second code, what you wrote was `n! = (n-1)*n!`

Answer (score 2):

The second code is infinitely recursive. You keep calling `factorial(x)` over and over again.

The first version subtracts `1` from `x` each call, so eventually `x` will hit your base case, which is `x == 1`.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to go through the stack trace that you failed to provide.  Let's take a look at the expansion of each function for 3!

First function:

```
factorial(3)
factorial(2) * 3
factorial(1) * 2 * 3
1 * 2 * 3
```

... which results in the expected answer, 6

Second function:

```
factorial(3)
factorial(3) * 2
factorial(3) * 2 * 2
factorial(3) * 2 * 2 * 2
factorial(3) * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2
```

... which will eventually overflow the stack (meaning :-) that you've come to the right web site for an answer).

In short, the second one doesn't work because it's algebraically **wrong**, as well as infinitely recursive.  As others have already pointed out, you make an identical call each time, with no way to end the recursion.